# Convergence of probability for $t$-distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Assume that $Z_0,Z_1,Z_2,\dots$ are i.i.d. RVs, $Z_j\sim N(0,1)$, and set
$$T_n:=\frac{Z_0}{\sqrt{\frac1n(Z_1^2+\cdots+Z_n^2)}}$$
(a) Compute the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\text{P}(T_n^2+2T_n\leq x)\text{,$\ \ \ $  $x\in\mathbb R$}$$

Can someone give me a hint as to how to start this question? I know that $T_n$ is a $T$-distribution but other than that I have no idea how to start it.

So by LLN I have found that the limiting distribution as $n$ tends to $ \infty$ is $Z_0$, then to find the limit I have arrived at:

$$lim_{n->\infty} \mathbf P((T_n+1)^2 \le 1+x))$$

I'm tempted to take the square root of both sides but as $x$ can be lesser than $-1$ the square root would be imaginary and this is where I am stuck.

Comment: Do you know the law of large numbers?

Comment: Would you care to look at my question again?

Comment: I fail to see how $x<-1$ is a problem since anyway, if $x<-1$ then, for every $n$, the event $[T_n^2+2T_n\leqslant x]$ is the empty set. In particular, the value of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P(T_n^2+2T_n\leqslant x)$ is rather clear.

Comment: Yep I believe that I figured it out! I will write up my answer later hopefully it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

We can show and use the following

> **Lemma.** Let $(X_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ be a sequence of random variables  such that $X_n\to X$ in probability and the cumulative distribution function of $X$ is continuous. Then for each $t\in\mathbf R$, the following convergence holds:
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P(X_n\leqslant t)=\mathbb P(X\leqslant t). $$